# How to convert the following SQL query to Linq?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008

How to convert following SQL query to Linq?

```
select day(Ser_CallDate) as OrderDate, count(*) TotalCall
from ServiceCalls
where month(Ser_CallDate) = MONTH(getdate()) and year(Ser_CallDate) = YEAR(getdate())
group by day(Ser_CallDate)
```

Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = ServiceCalls
        .Where(s => s.Ser_CallDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
            && s.Ser_CallDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
        .GroupBy(s => s.Ser_CallDate)
        .Select(g => new {
                OrderDate = g.Key,
                TotalCall = g.Count()})
        .ToList();
```